# How to run Python scripts in Visual Studio Code with Code Runner in a Windows command prompt while showing errors in integrated panel?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-code-runner

By default, running a `.py` file through VSCode Code Runner executes the program in the VSCode integrated terminal:
[image: Terminal]
I would like it to do exactly what it does in the integrated terminal, but launch the code through a separate Windows command prompt, like PyCharm.

If I go into `settings.json` in VSCode, I could change `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,` to `false`, it will execute the code in the `output` tab instead of `terminal` tab.
[image]
This doesn't help me much.

From `settings.json` I can change:

[image]

to:

[image]

This executes the program in the external terminal I want, but it has some serious drawbacks. For one, I have to add `input()` at the end of my code every time in order for it not to automatically close. The bigger problem is that if I have some kind of logical error in my code, it won't show me any type of error message; just closes the command prompt.

Is there any way to have the code execute in an external Windows command prompt, show all error messages (either in VSCode or terminal itself), and have the terminal require input to close without needing the `input()` function at the end of my code?

Comment: I think the following answer has solved the problem, but you still feel dissatisfied. Would you please describe in detail what you expect? CMD or vscode?

Comment: I left a comment under that answer as to why it doesn't exactly work for me. Having to switch to cmd every time, type out the directory/ file name, especially with different files can get cumbersome. Looking for a quick way to run the code in the windows CMD with a single key-press or button; one that shows tracebacks. If you've ever used PyCharm, or Visual Studio, they both have that feature.

Comment: Then I don't think this question is suitable to be asked here in vscode

Answer (score 0):

You can open windows terminal/command prompt from the start menu, navigate to your python file and use the same python command to run the python file that you used in VSCode.

[enter image description here][1]

You won't need to add "input()" to your code and you will also get tracebacks.

EDIT: reuploaded picture.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzQz2.png

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. Having to type the name every time, hassle with different directories; all a bit too tedious. Would like something more immediate, the ability to run from keybind any file I'm currently focused on. I appreciate the suggestion, though.